# Devise and localized own mail template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, devise, actionmailer

I'm using devise gem and want to translate confirmation mail. I already got my own template and overridden mailer method:

```
class LocalizedDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def confirmation_instructions(record, locale)
    @locale = locale
    super
  end
end
```

So, in my template I can do something like that:

```
I18n.locale = @locale
```

And then:

```
t("it.really.works")
```

But I don't know how to pass my variable with locale to mailer method. What is the best way to do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Devise is offering the localisation of mail template "natively".

have a look at the devise source code

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb
In this file is explained how to localise the subject (to be added to your locales files)

```
  # Setup a subject doing an I18n lookup. At first, it attemps to set a subject
  # based on the current mapping:
  #
  #   en:
  #     devise:
  #       mailer:
  #         confirmation_instructions:
  #           user_subject: '...'
  #
```

This is then the body template that you need to localise as any other html.erb

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

Depending if your new user will sign_up using `http://yoursite/it/users/sign_up` or `http://yoursite/en/users/sign_up` (as you would normally do in your routes for your localised application) the good localised subject and mail (in the former case in Italian, in the latter in English) will be sent.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was trying that solution, but it fails when I haven't got locale in path and the template is custom (made by me, not provided by devise). Unfortunately, I'm not able to change routing, so probably only solution is to add locale field in User model.

Comment: You can specify a default locale in your routes http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html `scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|it/ do
  resources :users
end` and your custom template will be used instead (the template overwritten from `rails generate devise:views`)

Comment: Of course, but I'm not allowed to do that in this project. Its not depend on me this time. Anyway, thanks for help. I had to add locale attribute to user model, and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to add a `locale` column to your User model and use your own mailer.
This way you have also more flexibility, if you plan to set your own stylesheets and `from` fields or add additional mails.

in `config/initializer/devise.rb`:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.mailer = "UserMailer"
  ...
end
```

in `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
  default from: "noreply@yourdomain.com"

  def confirmation_instructions(user)
    @user = user
    set_locale(@user)
    mail to: @user.email
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(user)
    @user = user
    set_locale(@user)
    mail to: @user.email
  end

  def unlock_instructions(user)
    @user = user
    set_locale(@user)
    mail to: @user.email
  end

  private
   def set_locale(user)
     I18n.locale = user.locale || I18n.default_locale
   end
end
```

Comment: Isn't this the right method signature for devise 3.1rc2? def reset_password_instructions(user, token, opts={})

Comment: @IvailoBardarov i just edited it to use the appropriate signatures with latest devise

Answer (score 2):

One more way is to add the initializer:

```
require 'devise/mailer'

module Devise
  class Mailer
    module Localized
      %w(
        confirmation_instructions
        reset_password_instructions
        unlock_instructions
      ).each do |method|
        define_method(method) do |resource, *args|
          I18n.with_locale(resource.try(:locale)) do
            super(resource, *args)
          end
        end
      end
    end

    prepend Localized
  end
end
```

For ruby <2.1 you can use concern with `alias_method_chain`.

Comment: Thanks ! I find this smart !

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do that is add it on record. So you can add a locale column in your User or juste add an `attr_accessor :locale` in your User model

So you just need define this locale in your record and use it with `I18n.locale = record.locale`